# MYSQL ROW_COUNT always returns 0 when saving to variable

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get ROW_COUNT to work and I've looked at all the other answers but none worked. Below is a simple update statement after which I want to print the rows affected.

```
UPDATE table_name SET table_name.INLINECOMMENT2 = "XXXXT" WHERE table_name.ID<25710;
SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO @results;
SELECT @results;
--- SET @results = (SELECT ROW_COUNT()); --- also doesn't work
```

The output:
/* Affected rows: 6  Found rows: 1  Warnings: 0  Duration for 3 queries: 1,032 sec. */
@results always show 0

This query was run on MYSQL Version: 5.7.30-log

Any ideas? Are there other ways to get the affected rows?

Comment: Use SET, not SELECT INTO.

Comment: "The output: /* Affected rows: 6 Found rows: 1 Warnings: 0 Duration for 3 queries: 1,032 sec. */" - what tool produces this output? this is not MySQl diagnostic.

Comment: Hi Akina, I tried both HeidiSQL and DBeaver as tools to test this. Also the SET option was also tried as mentioned

Comment: This might a tool problem. Just ran the same query on MySQL Workbench and then it showed the right answer :P